# Fixed div then relative but with current top position

Tags: css, skrollr

I'm trying to make a garage door effect with scrolling. (I'm using skrollr for the scrolling position) While scrolling a sliding garage door is translated vertically with negative values. Under the garage door is a fixed element. When the door reaches `translateY(-100%)` I want the fixed element to be relative. I achieved it with the skrollr BUT here is the problem. When I'm making it relative it goes suddenly to the top of the page. I want it stay in its position and scroll normally. This happens because of the scrollbar position. Here is the first try with keyframes

`data-0="position:fixed; top:0px;" data-200="position:relative;"`

But with this goes to the top of the page based on the scrollbar. I've tried to adjust the top value

`data-0="position:fixed; top:0px;" data-199="position:fixed; top:0px;" data-200="position:relative; top:200px;"`

But it in position 199-200 it makes an annoying flashing.

I thought to add an `overflow-y:hidden` to the body but then the door isn't sliding (duh :p ).

[Here is the link](http://hambos22.me/test/). I know, it's a bit confusing, but if you'll see the website you gonna understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see `data-200="position:relative; top:0;"`, not `200px`. Could you set top to this value (again?) or provide a pen/jsfiddle/code that can be modified?

Comment: well I solved the problem by adding a transparent box which reveals itself after the 200px scroll, in top of the intro section. Now its smooth and it works. For your comment though, it doesn't need the "px" suffix.

Comment: I meant top: 200px instead of top: 0

Comment: I've done all the combinations already  ☺ check again the url which I  provided in the OP